# grok pattern match not working

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have this pattern and I want the grok filter for this:

```
24 May 2016 23:04:03,003 [] [] [] INFO  [listenerContainer-35] com.newworld.mmp.orderlist.NewDataUtil -  | 1464048002998 | 201605233157123319 | Account | 67578625
09896 | DHW | 2016-05-23T23:59:56.621Z | 2016-05-24T00:00:02.676Z | STARTED PROCESSING
```

I wrote the pattern but it is incomplete:

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} 20%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}) %{DATA:junk} %{DATA:junk} %{DATA:junk} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:junk1} %{JAVACLASS:class}
```

The `%{POSINT:mynewint} or %{NUMBER:mynewint}` for the 1464048002998 is not working.

Like `%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} 20%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}) %{DATA:junk} %{DATA:junk} %{DATA:junk} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:junk1} %{JAVACLASS:class}- | %{POSINT:mynewint}`

I need help on this and the complete grok expression?

Comment: What are the fields you are expecting in the output? Can you please explain about your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your Log line:

```
24 May 2016 23:04:03,003 [] [] [] INFO  [listenerContainer-35] com.newworld.mmp.orderlist.NewDataUtil -  | 1464048002998 | 201605233157123319 | Account | 6757862509896 | DHW | 2016-05-23T23:59:56.621Z | 2016-05-24T00:00:02.676Z | STARTED PROCESSING

SAMPLE GROK PATTERN that matches your log record: 
%{MONTHDAY:MonthDay} %{MONTH:Month} %{YEAR:Year} %{TIME:Time} \[] \[] \[] %{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}  %{NOTSPACE:ListenerContainer} %{JAVACLASS:JavaClass} -  \| %{NUMBER:Number1} \| %{NUMBER:Number2} \| %{WORD:Account} \| %{NUMBER:Number3} \| %{WORD:DHW} \| %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Timestamp1} \| %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Timestamp2} \| %{JAVALOGMESSAGE:LogMessage}
```

This will give output fields as follows:

- MonthDay = 24
- Month = May
- Year = 2016
- Time = 23:04:03,003
- LogLevel = INFO
- ListenerContainer = [listenerContainer-35]
- JavaClass = com.newworld.mmp.orderlist.NewDataUtil
- Number1 = 1464048002998
- Number2 = 201605233157123319
- Account
- Number3 = 6757862509896
- DHW
- Timestamp1 = 2016-05-23T23:59:56.621Z
- Timestamp2 = 2016-05-24T00:00:02.676Z
- LogMessage = STARTED PROCESSING

You can try your own grok filters, create parse and test on the following site: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/construction